# Map an object that having list inside to another object with the list

Tags: kotlin, rx-android

I am trying to map an object1 to another object2. but the object1 have a list in it.
This is my code. but when but I am getting error saying can not be cast.
This is the object I am getting from API

```
    interface  Api {


    @GET("/api/")
    fun getUsers(@Query("results") results: Int): Single<Dto.Users>


    sealed class Dto {
        data class Users(
            @SerializedName("results") var resultDto: List<Result>
        ) : Dto()

        data class Result(
            var cell: String,
            var email: String,
            var gender: String,
            var name: Name,
            var nat: String,
            var phone: String
        ) : Dto()

        data class Name(
            var first: String,
            var last: String,
            var title: String
        ) : Dto()


    }

}
```

Another data class to map with.

```
sealed class Entity {

    data class Users(
        val results: List<Result>
    ) : Entity()


    data class Result(
        var cell: String,
        var email: String,
        var gender: String,
        var name: Name,
        var nat: String,
        var phone: String
    ) : Entity()

    data class Name(
        var first: String,
        var last: String,
        var title: String
    ) : Entity()


}
```

This is extension function I am using to convert dto to entity.

```
    Api.Dto.Users.map() = Entity.Users(
    resultDto.map { result ->
        Entity.Result(
            result.cell,
            result.email,
            result.gender,
            Entity.Name(result.name.first, result.name.last, result.name.title),
            result.nat,
            result.phone
        )
    }
)
```

And how I am using the extension function to convert dto to entity.

```
  val data = dataFromServer.applyIoScheduler().map { userObj -> { userObj.map() } }
```

Comment: Show the code for `Entity` and `Dto` classes

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve . Add some more information for the same . Is this clean architecture what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: @mightyWOZ Updated the code  of classes.

Comment: @KARUNESHPALEKAR Yes, I am learning clean architecture, What is issue is, I am getting the response as DTO class but later I want to convert the DTO object in Entity object.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to setup your example. As mentioned you missed `Api`, `Dto`, `Entity`. But after adding them, I got a working example (can compile). Because of the equal class name, it's not easy to understand it. Maybe you also struggled with it and linked the wrong types? Was this your intension?:

```kotlin
open class Entity {
    data class Users(
        var resultDto: List<Entity.Result>
    ) : Dto()

    data class Result(
        var cell: String,
        var email: String,
        var gender: String,
        var name: Entity.Name,
        var nat: String,
        var phone: String
    ) : Dto()

    data class Name(
        var first: String,
        var last: String,
        var title: String
    ) : Dto()
}

open class Dto {

    data class Users(
        val results: List<Dto.Result>
    ) : Entity()


    data class Result(
        var cell: String,
        var email: String,
        var gender: String,
        var name: Dto.Name,
        var nat: String,
        var phone: String
    ) : Entity()

    data class Name(
        var first: String,
        var last: String,
        var title: String
    ) : Entity()
}

fun Dto.Result.map(): Entity.Users {
    return Entity.Users(
        listOf(this).map { result ->
            Entity.Result(
                result.cell,
                result.email,
                result.gender,
                Entity.Name(result.name.first, result.name.last, result.name.title),
                result.nat,
                result.phone
            )
        })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I am not sure how to use your function. would you please write an extension method for this?

Comment: I changed to map method into an extension and skipped the local variables. This makes the code more concise, but may irritate people which are not familiar with [Kotlin Extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html).